# Estruturar uma base de dados

Tags: sql

Bom Dia. Estou a estruturar uma base de dados para um projeto e gostaria de saber se é possível haver uma base de dados(ou tabela) apenas com chaves estrangeiras para ligar a todas as outras tabelas, ou é obrigatório ter uma chave primária?

Comment: O ideal é que toda tabela tenha uma chave primária, isto é uma maneira de identificar cada linha desta tabela. Note que pode ser uma chave primária composta de todos os seus atributos. A não existência de uma chave primária permite que você possa incluir linhas duplicadas, o que não parece fazer muito sentido em seu modelo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sim, é possível, não é obrigatório ter chave primária, mas com a chave primária é que pode identificar qual a linha especifica da tabela que quer.

Exemplo:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].People(
    ID int NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (ID))

CREATE TABLE [dbo].Persons(
    ID int NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (ID))


CREATE TABLE Orders (
    PersonID int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Persons(ID),
    PeopleID int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES People(ID)
);

select * from People
select * from Persons
select * from Orders 

Drop table Orders
Drop table People
Drop table Persons
```